# Derby embedded executable jar suddenly read only

Tags: java, database, inno-setup, derby, executable-jar

when I ran my program in eclipse I could have written to the derby table and query as well, but now I've build my executable jar file the program is only able to query the database anymore and the insert statement does not work at all. There can't be any coding mistakes as the query still works... is there maybe any lack of permission or something going on pls advise... tried many different things but nothing worked.

Comment: if the file is on a RO filesystem it will be RO

Comment: so obvious when you mention it but I would never thought of this on my own !! Thank you :) but how do I request permission to write on the database on a Windows hard drive ... ?  I'm using launch4j for the exe and Inno setup for the installer. is there any chance to request permission for writing on the database ( hard drive ) of the user who is using my program ?

Comment: Sorry it has been about 15 years since I last used Inno Setup, so I can not help.

Comment: I've figured it out on my own now, all I had to do was changing the default installation folder from the Inno setup wizard to any other folder than programs folder as it is of course read only on Windows ... simple as it is but thank you for always replying super quickly to my questions really appreciate the support

Comment: The correct solution is to install the application to `Program Files`, but database to a user profile or `ProgramData`.